# GGplot, as.factor transformation issue: on label x (factors 1 and 3) R uses continuous numbers instead (1, 2, 3)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have the following issue:
in the first column (Codice) I have numbers as site codes, but I as you may guess I want to use them not as numbers but as site names, so factors. I've modified the column with as.factor command, and it worked fine, but when trying to plot a boxplot with the pH from the sites (which have levels only "1" and "3")

```
ggplot(test_valori, aes(group=Codice, x=Codice, y=pH, fill=Codice)) + 
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE)
```

this is what I get:

[image]

on the x axis, instead of using the factors 1 and 3 as in the data, it uses 1, 2 and 3 as if counting normally.

Anybody knows how to fix this? I tried searching for a way to let R understand that on the x axis I want the factors in the column "Codice"

Edit:
Thanks to @Seth for the advice (it's my first time here on stack overflow): here is the whole dataset of "test_valori", the small file I tried to use to learn boxplotting, along with the code I tried to use to treat "Codice" as a factor (I paste it as a text here because I don't see any attachment button, otherwise I'd attach the .csv)

[Codice pH
1   7,58
1   7,34
1   7,63
1   7,65
1   7,62
1   7,48
1   7,70
1   7,73
1   7,48
3   6,49
3   7,45
3   7,60
3   7,46
3   7,14
3   7,63
3   7,66
3   7,36
3   7,38](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XevOu.png) Edit: I see now the after inserting it vertically with correct, layout, the site automaticall sets it horizontally and it becomes impossible to understand anything, so I've pasted an image, (just click on the numbers of "test_valori")

The command I used to change "Codice" to factor was:

as.factor(test_valori$Codice)

Thanks again for the reply @Seth!

Edit n2: Thanks @Jon! I did it immediately, here it is:

dput(test_valori)
structure(list(Codice = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), pH = c(7.58, 7.34, 7.63,
7.65, 7.62, 7.48, 7.7, 7.73, 7.48, 6.49, 7.45, 7.6, 7.46, 7.14,
7.63, 7.66, 7.36, 7.38)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-18L))

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Mars_87, to make this a reproducible problem please edit the question to include a representative sample of `test_valori` along with the code you're using to treat `Codice` as a factor.

Comment: A superb way to share the data would be to run `dput(test_valori)` and paste the output into your question. That will capture the data structure and data types, which are often very helpful for getting on the same page. An image is not helpful, since we can only use it by retyping it (no thanks!) and we won't necessarily have the same data structure and data types as you.

Comment: Running `as.factor()` is not going to change your data frame. To be sure the object itself is being modified, try `test_valori$Codice <- as.factor(test_valori$Codice)` before creating the plot.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot Seth! And thanks to you too Jon!

Answer (score 0):

your issue doesnt appear reproducible, even when I force the data to have the absent level; ggplot2 is not choosing to show it on the axis

```
test_valori <- structure(list(Codice = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                              pH = c(7.58, 7.34, 7.63, 7.65, 7.62, 7.48, 7.7, 7.73, 
                                     7.48, 6.49, 7.45, 7.6, 7.46, 7.14, 7.63, 7.66, 7.36, 7.38)),
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
test_valori$Codice <- factor(test_valori$Codice,levels=(1:3))
test_valori
test_valori$Codice 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test_valori, aes(group=Codice, x=Codice, y=pH, fill=Codice)) + 
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE)
```

I would guess that level 2 isnt absent from your data but present; and so you would need to filter it out.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nir, actually it's quite odd. The levels are for sure only 1 and 3 both on the native excel and asking R who confirmed it so I'm a little puzzled about this. Anyway in the end it worked just fine, it was me just typing the wrong command to set the data as factor:-)